# Hawtio executable jar always "Failed to log in, Forbidden"

Tags: activemq-classic, hawtio

I'm trying to put hawtio-1.4.11 to work, but failing. I'm using the simplest configuration.
In the same host, activemq-5.9.0 (clean, no configs), and I just run java -jar hawtio-app-1.4.11.jar.
I've tested the logins to activemq (both old console and hawtio) and it was working ok.
Then I accessed hawtio

```
http://my_ip_address:8080/hawtio
```

and filled the form, and I was redirected to the login page. Then when I click login, I get "Failed to log in, Forbidden".

Could not see any log messages the give me a hint.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Update:

I did the fowlling test:

```
wget --user admin --password admin --auth-no-challenge http://localhost:8161/hawtio/jolokia/read/org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost/TotalConsumerCount
```

And it worked (HTTP 200), and using a wrong password (HTTP 403). It seems to be working as it supposed to, but still can not make hawtio standalone to connect.
When I try to login using hawtio, the only log messages are those (regardless if I used the correct password or not):

```
2014-07-17 19:08:47,342 | DEBUG | Handling request for path /auth/login | io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter | qtp962581073-40
2014-07-17 19:08:47,342 | DEBUG | Doing authentication and authorization for path /auth/login | io.hawt.web.AuthenticationFilter | qtp962581073-40
```

BTW, I've tried a lot of different setups, including war version in jboss-4.2.3 but all failed too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this blog entry how to install hawtio in ActiveMQ as the web console

- http://sensatic.net/activemq/activemq-and-hawtio.html

It also explains to setup the security part, which is likely what is your problem.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. I already have -Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.role=admins but it simply don't accept login from the executable jar.

Comment: I tried using the versions 5.9.1 and 5.10.0 of activemq and it simply worked on first attempt. I believe that it has something to do with activemq-5.9.0. So I'll just upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to login to activemq console, but not in hawtio.

In my case I found that:

- activemq console credetial are read from conf/jetty-realm.properties
- hawtio credential are read from conf/users.properties and conf/groups.properties

In users.properties the password cannot contains same characters, in my case the euro sign €

Comment: Hi, read your comment on the blog as well. Can you let me know how you has resolved this?

Comment: I simply put same credential on all configuration files stated in my answer using only characters [A-Za-z0-9_]

Comment: Got it, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue: get always a hawtio (1.4.45) styled login page when try to remote connect to ActiveMQ jolokia api (ActiveMQ 5.10.1)

The reason was that **the URL-paht configured in hawtio, that points to ActiveMQ jolokia api must end with an `/`**!

for example `/api/jolokia/`

Answer (score 0):

On a Unix machine - I fixed this through changing the order of the configurationpath to the configuration scripts. Added /bin/env as the first statment in the /bin/activemq script under # CONFIGURATION # For using instances,

since it ignores the others but the first as stated here

[Unix configuration](http://activemq.apache.org/unix-shell-script.html)

happy coding !